# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement - NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

I have this query as a property constant:

```
get.policy.list=SELECT policy FROM table WHERE policy IN (:policyList) AND state = :state
```

On feeding and getting a list from the jdbcTemplate, I get:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL
>   statement

on the first line inside the try block.

```
@Override
    public List<MyVO> areValidPolicies(String state, List<String> policyList) {

        MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("state", state)
                .addValue("policyList", policyList);

        List<MyVO> retrievedPolicyList = new ArrayList<MyVO>();

        try{
            retrievedPolicyList = myNamedJdbcTemplate.query("SELECT policy FROM table WHERE policy IN (:policyList) AND state = :state", namedParameters, new RowMapper<MyVO>() {

                        @Override
                        public MyVO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                            MyVO myVO = new MyVO();
                            MyVO.setPolicy(rs.getString("policy"));
                            return myVO;
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        retrievedPolicyList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

        return retrievedPolicyList;
    }
```

**Stack trace**:

```
 org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [get.policy.list]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:684)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:711)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:761)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:192)
    at com.project.policyImpl.areValidPolicies(ESRepublishDaoImpl.java:56)
    at com.project.policyImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$683fad37.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
```

Please guide on where am I getting wrong.

Comment: Did you try use alias for the selected table like:
"SELECT t.policy FROM table t WHERE t.policy IN (:policyList) AND t.state = :state"?

Comment: Yes @SándorJuhos. Didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to switching on SQL statements logging to see what your Spring app is invoking under the hood on the database?

Answer (score 2):

`table` is a reserved word in SQL. I suggest renaming the table to avoid future hassle, but if that's not an option, you could escape it by using double quotes (`"`):

```
 retrievedPolicyList = 
     myNamedJdbcTemplate.query("SELECT policy FROM \"table\" WHERE policy IN (:policyList) AND state = :state", namedParameters, new RowMapper<MyVO>() {
     // Here --------------------------------------^^-----^^
```

Comment: Thanks @Mureinik for your response. But table is not my exact table. I have renamed it to be an example.